# How do I purposely corrupt a good line art drawing so it looks like this image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, image-editing, character-styles

Please check below for the difference. One of them is pixelated and sharp and the other one is smooth and clear. I want to purposely corrupt the good image so the style looks like the bad image. What would you suggest in this particular case? The closer the corruption resembles to the pixellated image the better!

[image: clean hi rez line art]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Threshold will do most of that. Use a combination of threshold and levels, then you can also convert to bitmap as a final step

Comment: @Inkplay_ I might try blurring it a little before using threshold. That gives threshold a little more to work with.